# Odoo, how to make that an user can only see his partners (through parent_id field)

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

In Odoo every partner has a parent_id field.
In my Odoo app I want to make that an user can only see their contacts (partners). That means that an user can only see those contacts in which they are the parent contact. I created the following record rule for this purpose, but it is not working, the user can see all contacts, whether they are the parent or not. What am I doing wrong?

```
  <record model="ir.rule" id="portabilidad_client_record_rule">
    <field name="name">See only His client</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_res_partner"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('parent_id.id','=',user.partner_id.id)]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('portabilidad_store'))]"/>
</record>
```

Comment: Have you checked for other record rules for `res.partner`? Record rules with groups (not global) are logically linked by OR, so if there are more rules, they could bypass your new rule. And you don't need the `.id` after `parent_id`.